# "djay for iPad" How do they do it?

Tags: ios

for anyone that have seen the new ["djay for iPad" application](http://www.algoriddim.com/djay-ipad), how have they managed to access and manipulate tracks from the iTunes music library? So far it was only possible to playback the music with the `MPMusicPlayerController`. I have looked at iOS 4.2 but could not find any new features that indicates the trick.

Any idea?

André

Answer (score 1):

It isn't actually manipulating the files in iTunes. It is reading them in and copying them to do the manipulations.

Comment: So there is delay for file conversion before you can play? I haven't tried the app yet but the website says "Direct access to your iTunes library (gives you instant access to all your existing songs)". Which would be misleading.

Comment: It has access to the songs, but when you start manipulating them, it is manipulating a copy, not the actual file in iTunes.

Comment: So there would be a delay for copying the files from the iPod library, wouldn't it?

Comment: @André - Yeah, probably something of a delay, but it all depends on what they are actually doing. I haven't looked at the app, just read the descriptions of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You've been able to stream from the iPod library since iOS 4.1. Have a look at AVFoundation.